# How to finding unique elements in a column without sorting in bash?

Tags: bash, unique, columnsorting

I am trying to find unique occurrences of elements in one of the columns (2nd col to be specific) of a data file using bash. I don't want the output to be sorted or randomized. After searching a lot,I found a solution based on 'awk' which partially worked:

`awk '{arr[$2] = 1} END {for (key in arr) {print key}}' input_file > output_file`

but output seems to be random. I wish to perform this operation in such a way that, for each element, it's last occurrence is checked. Or in other words 'uniqueness' is checked starting from the end of the file. As an example if the elements are in the following order:

`5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 8, 5, 6, 9, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12`

then the output should be:

`7, 8, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12`

Comment: Please do wrap your samples into Code tags,I am on mobile now so couldn't do it fully.

Comment: AND are you only interested in duplicates? What should happen to a single value? Good luck.

Comment: please update the question with a more detailed explanation of how you obtain the desired output; the only number I see (in the example input) that's **unique** is '7'

Comment: I have update the question to show how single values should be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach by reading file twice:-

```
awk 'NR==FNR{++A[$2];next}A[$2]==++T[$2]' input_file input_file
```

Comment: This works for me! I just add  '| awk {'print $2'}' to print just the just column. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. I am in cab so couldn't test it should work.

`awk '!a[$2]++{b[++count]=$2} END{for(j=1;j<=count;j++){print b[j]}}'  Input_file`

This should give you output in correct order in which 2nd field is coming in Input_file + this will take care of uniqueness of that field.

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program here.
!a[$2]++{                       ##Checking condition if $2 is present in array a if NOT present then increase counter in index of array a with $2.
  b[++count]=$2                 ##Creating an array named b whose index is count variable with its increment count and its value is $2.
}
END{                            ##Starting END block of this awk program here.
  for(j=1;j<=count;j++){        ##Starting for loop here from j=1 to till value of count.
    print b[j]                  ##Printing value of array b with index of variable j here which is $2 of lines.
  }                             ##Closing BLOCK for for loop here.
}
'  Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This gives me sorted data.

Comment: @Aman_X, it will NOT sort any data, this will give data in sequence of in which $2 is coming in your Input_file. Let me know if this helps you?

Comment: thanks for the clarification. It seems to me that with this solution , the first occurrence of each element is preserved while going from top to bottom. This made me mistakenly believe that the data is sorted. Anyway, I can share the actual data file if you want.

Comment: @Aman_X, Added explanation for my code now let me know if any questions here.